# Software to generate all layout possibilities within a set of color

Tags: user-interface, color

Is there a software that generates all possible color combinations for a specified layout?
For example, I'm designing a website layout and I have a color palette.

[image: Colour palette]

I want to see all the possibilities within that set of colors to better choose the right layout for the website:
[image: Basic layout in different colour combinations]

Comment: Do you care about pricing? How about what OS will you want to use this on? Is a web-app okay?

Comment: For now I'm not worried about the cost. It would be best if it was for a Mac. Yes it could be a web-app

Comment: How would the tool apply the color to the website? Is there a CSS file with placeholders?

Comment: It doesn't have to generate the final layout in `HTML` or `CSS`, I'm just looking for a piece of software that lets me experiment several color palettes by experimenting all possible color combinations in the sections defined by me

Comment: And how do the sections defined by you get colored?

Comment: Could you provide more info? The colors are defined by image as above, (so need analyze it for colors) or you have rgb values? Want generate 25 images (5x5 combinations) (if yes, how big?) - or you want get 25 different colored web pages? The layout is always left-menu + top-menu (e.g. two color combination?). Could you install command line utilities on OS X (like macports.org?) Are you OK with the Terminal.app and scripts?

Comment: Just write a chunk of CSS to detect mouse position, and apply a color scheme depending on where the mouse is.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) (batch image processing program).

For OS X, the best you can do is:

1. [install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. open new Terminal.app window (or relog)
3. run: `port install ImageMagick`
4. it installs a few open source packages (it may take a while)

And finally run the attached script to get the next image:

[image: 20 different color combinations]

At the end of of this post is the script, save it for example with name `mktiles` and you can modify it yourself. But you need to know a bit Bash and the ImageMagick suite of commands (convert and montage).

The usage:

```
bash mktiles num_of_colors color_image_file final_image_name.ext
```

Meanaing of arguments:

- `num_of_colors`: number of colors from the image (the first *N* most used)
- `color_image_file`: your palette image file
- `final_image_name.ext`: the desired image file name of the result (the extension determines the type)

E.g. for your example:

```
bash mktiles 5 xY1j5.png final.jpg
```

(I uploaded the final.jpg above.)

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iw=300 #width
ih=200 #height
mw=$(( $iw * 33 / 100 ))
th=$(( $ih * 10 / 100 ))
tmpdir=/tmp/tiles.$$

getcolors_image() {
    convert "$1" -colors "${2:-5}" -unique-colors txt:- | sed -n 's/.*\(#[A-Z0-F][A-Z0-F][A-Z0-F][A-Z0-F][A-Z0-F][A-Z0-F]\).*/\1/p'
}

do_image() {
    filename="$tmpdir/$1-$2.png"
    convert -size ${iw}x${ih} xc:none \
        -fill "$1" -draw "rectangle 0,0 $mw,$ih" \
        -fill "$2" -draw "rectangle 0,0 $iw,$th" \
        "$filename"
}

case "$#" in
3) colors="$1"; input="$2"; final="$3" ;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 numcolors input_image output_image" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
esac

mkdir -p $tmpdir
declare -a colors=($(getcolors_image "$input" "$numcolors"))
tile=$(( ${#colors[@]} - 1 ))

for top in ${colors[@]}
do
    for left in ${colors[@]}
    do
        [[ "$top" == "$left" ]] && continue
        do_image "$top" "$left"
    done
done

montage $tmpdir/* -tile $((${#colors[@]} - 1))x${#colors[@]} "$final"
rm -rf "$tmpdir"
```

The script of course is far from ideal, but you can get the idea.

With a similar technique you can generate 20 HTML pages with embedded CSS & colors and the like. Learning Bash scripting on OS X can be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Design a palette and check how would it look like in a website:
http://www.paletton.com/

Bootstrap color theme designer with preview
http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/